# INSERT with selected value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

From the Table:

```
user   | groupId
-------------------------
A      | 1
B      | 1
B      | 2
C      | 1
C      | 3
```

I would like to find all the records without groupId = 2 and thus insert it, something like that:

```
INSERT INTO Table (user, groupId) VALUES (SELECT user FROM Table WHERE groupId != '2' GROUP BY user, '2')
```

result should be like this:

```
user   | groupId
-------------------------
A      | 1
A      | 2
B      | 1
B      | 2
C      | 1
C      | 2
C      | 3
```

Since there are too many records I can't do it one by one or separate more than one query. Can somebody help me to finish it? thanks!

Comment: btw I'm using msssql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `insert . . . select`:

```
INSERT INTO Table (user, groupId) 
    SELECT user, 2
    FROM Table 
    GROUP BY user
    HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN groupId = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0;
```